# Flutter - hide/show two banners by tapping n screen

Tags: android, iphone, flutter

I have been using flutter for a very short time. I want to create an action but I have no idea how to do this. I hope to find some help. I would like to create an action : when i tap once on my screen, this action makes appear two banners. One on the top and another on the bottom of my screen and when i tap another time on the screen the banners disappear (you can see what i mean on the picture).

Do you have an idea how to do this ?

PS: sorry for my bad english.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a global variable eg-

bool _isVisible = true,

then

wrap any widget that you want to hide or then show in Visibility widget,

```
Visibility(
//replace container with your desired widget
  child: Container(),
  visible: _isVisible, 
),
```

After that,

Flutter has a useful widget called GestureDetector. Just wrap any other widget into it, in your case the overall screen widget.

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
_isVisible = !_isvisible;
});
  },
//Replace container with the widget that you using for screen
child: Container()
)
```

setState() function is used for resetting the state according to the changes it make.

Finally, the most important thing use StatefulWidget.

Here is a youtube video to learn more about statefulWidget [How Stateful Widgets Are Used Best - Flutter Widgets](https://youtu.be/AqCMFXEmf3w)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I really appreciate it !

Comment: Did you not get your answer? Let me know.

Comment: I did not have the time to try what you advised me. I will keep you posted when i will try. thx

Comment: Man it works thank you very much !!! You are the best !

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html), that enables you to recognized gestures on the screen. In this situation, you can wrap all your page on a GestureDetector to recognize the gesture onTap, then you create a variable isTaped that will change every time the user tap on the screen, now with this variable, you can use it to appear and despair the bars.

Some notes that can help you. You can use the [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) Widget to overlay the page and the bars. To finish you can use the [AnimatedOpacity](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedOpacity-class.html) to fade the bars when appear and dispair.

Comment: Thanks you ! I'm gonna try this now !